How to repair gel coat on cultured marble sink
What’s the best way to patch this sink? Doesn’t have to be pretty, just don’t want what’s under exposed.

There is no repair for a scar like that.
There are companies that will recoat the entire sink with a sprayed on ceramic.
However the cost may be greater than a new sink.

Yep.  If you want a temporary fix, maybe some kind of epoxy, then finish as you would for a bondo car repair.  Probably won't match colors, but will help protect what's under (if it even needs protecting).
